# What's a good egg substitute in pizza dough?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, pizza

I'm trying to perfect my pizza dough recipe, and build a device that measures out and adds the ingredients to the mixer automatically.

I'm using an egg in the recipe, but making a machine that cracks an egg and puts it in a bowl is too complex for me.

Is there an egg substitute that comes in either powder or liquid form that works well in pizza dough? Anyone had experiences using egg substitutes in pizza dough, and which ones worked/didn't work?

The future of pizza depends on it ;)

I thought the recipe would be helpful because the substitute might work better/worse depending on the other ingredients. The goal of the recipe is a fluffy, sort of sweet, soft pizza crust, and I usually do a Hungry Howie's style garlic herb seasoning on it.

1 cup milk

1/4 cup vegetable oil

1 tsp salt

1/4 cup sugar

1 egg

3 3/4 cup flour

2 tsp bread machine yeast

Comment: You *can* buy whole-eggs in liquid form, but you rarely see them in a normal grocery store because it's usually a product for commercial use. Restaurants rarely have time to split every egg individually, so they usually buy eggs by the liter in tetra packs.

Comment: I am surprised that you are using an egg at all. It is highly unusual for pizza dough. Can you really taste the difference, and if yes, do you find the eggy pizza better?

Comment: @rumtscho I'm testing it without egg right now. I changed water for milk, added the egg, and increased the sugar all at the same time from my last version and yes, it tastes way better than before. But I can't tell how much of that was due to the egg. I'll find out soon. Thanks for the simple sanity check about needing to find an egg substitute.

Comment: @moscafj, it worked. I can do it without the egg. It took a few tries, because I was getting the water temperature and rising time wrong, but now it works. Thank you. I would accept that as the answer if you put it in an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say that using an egg is unusual at all. I've seen loads of recipes which use egg including many "New York" style pizza doughs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like a recipe for pizza dough, rather it looks more like a naan or flatbread recipe. I am not exactly sure what you are aiming for, but why not simply eliminate the egg and increase the milk (or add water) by a small amount to compensate for the lost moisture?

Comment: OR use "Egg Beaters", pre-cracked and mixed eggs. Not sure if it has the same yolk as a normal egg though, which may change OP's outcome: https://www.eggbeaters.com/products/egg-beaters-original